# issues with the html 5 pattern attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make sure the input field pattern should work, but all i am getting is an error that format is wrong

```
<input type="text" id="Phone" name="Phone" maxlength="14" value="" class="required" required="" data-msg-required="Please enter the Telephone number." pattern="/^\(*\+*[1-9]{0,3}\)*-*[1-9]{0,3}[-. /]*\(*[2-9]\d{2}\)*[-. /]*\d{3}[-. /]*\d{4} *e*x*t*\.* *\d{0,4}$/" placeholder="(XXX) XXX-XXXX">
<input type="submit">
```

the number is automatically formatting to `(xxx) xxx-xxxx`

so what is wrong here

also i am trying to remove the message it displays if the value is invalid and add the red border to the input field

```
var cell = document.querySelector("input[name='cellphone']");
        cell.addEventListener('invalid', (function () {  
            return function (e) {    
            e.preventDefault();    
            var ele = document.getElementById("cellphone"); 
            $(ele).parents(".fui-form").addClass("fui-form-error");
        }; 
        })(), true);
```

Comment: Don't put `/` around the regexp in the `pattern` attribute.

Comment: that aid the pattern issuee

Comment: Please focus your question, you have both `name="Phone"` and `input[name='cellphone']` - perhaps edit using the snippet button and make a working example that illustrates and reproduces your issue with the smallest amount of code possible.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to just make sure that the input matches the pattern:
(XXX) XXX-XXXX, there are a couple things to take note of.

First of all, like Barmar said, when you use a regular expression in the pattern attribute of an HTML input element, that expression shouldn't be between forward slashes //.

Also, your regular expression is overly complicated.  You can just do something like this:

```js
// This javascript is just extra.  Not important part.

const form = document.forms[0]

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
    
  const { Phone: phone } = form.elements
    
  // you could also do \s{1} for one space instead of a plain space if you want
  console.log(phone.value, /\(\d{3}\)\s{1}\d{3}-\d{4}/.test(phone.value))
})
```

```html
<form>
  <input 
    type="text" 
    id="Phone" 
    name="Phone" 
    maxlength="14" 
    value="" 
    class="required" 
    required 
    data-msg-required="Please enter the Telephone number." 
    pattern="\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}" 
    placeholder="(XXX) XXX-XXXX"
  />
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Added a little extra JavaScript that will print the value of the input plus whether or not it matches the pattern.  However, if you try adding any value inside the input that doesn't match the pattern, the form won't submit.

---

Let's go through each part of the regular expression:

1. I first escape these `\(\)`, since I don't want to use them to capture a group.  I want them to be part of the actual pattern
2. I want there to be exactly 3 numbers within those first parentheses.  `\d` is shorthand for `[0-9]`, and `{3}` means I want 3 of them.
3. There must be one space.
4. Then we require 3 numbers followed by a hyphen (-) followed by 4 numbers.

---

#### If you don't want the default error message to appear, and you want to do something else in case of an error, here's an option:

```js
const form = document.forms[0]
const phone = form.elements.Phone
const regex = /\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}/

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  
  console.log(phone.value, regex.test(phone.value))
})

phone.addEventListener('input', e => {
  if (!regex.test(e.target.value)) {
    if (!phone.classList.contains('error'))
      phone.classList.add('error')
  } else {
    phone.classList.remove('error')
  }
})
```

```css
input[type='text'] {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgb(0 0 0 / 15%);
}

input:not(:focus).error {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input 
    type="text" 
    id="Phone" 
    name="Phone" 
    maxlength="14" 
    value="" 
    class="required" 
    required 
    data-msg-required="Please enter the Telephone number."
    placeholder="(XXX) XXX-XXXX"
  />
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I'm adding an event listener to the input which checks whether or not the user's input is valid after each new character typed.  If the user leaves the input box (not focused), and the value of the input doesn't match our pattern, the input has a red border.  If you're prefer some other behavior, you can just play with this code a little.

Comment: see this image, https://prnt.sc/1vr8xuu i do not want the mesage to appear and the border should red

Comment: Ah, in that case, you shouldn't use the HTML `pattern` attribute at all, just JavaScript.

Comment: well there should be someway of doing this, there is already a jqueryvalidation on it, but that is not properly working

Comment: Okay, just added another solution only using JavaScript.